# SSRS Interactive Sorting by fill color

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report that users would like sorted by fill color. Is it possible to do an interactive sorting expression to accomplish this? Or is there a better way to go about this? When the report runs there are conditional formatting rules in place that either make the fill yellow or grey. Want to get all the yellow items to the top of the report. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this [doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627509(v=sql.100).aspx) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same formatting rule to the interactive sort. So if you have the formatting rule as `=iif(Condition,"Yellow","Gray")`, then in the `Interactive Sort`, under `Sort By` expression write `=iif(Condition,1,2)`.